How to check if XFile exists?
I want to check if a file exists before downloading it in flutter web and mobile, so using File class is not possible since it uses dart:io and dart:io in not available in web. now I want to use XFile class for handling files in both web and mobile.
For File we can use bool exists = await file.exists();
but there is no exists() method for XFile types.
How can I check if a file already exits?

and await xfileToDownload.length() == 0 is not enough?

I will try it  .

Yes, and it needs a try catch. @pskink

ok, its good to know

I will accept the answer and add some info if you add it

feel free to post a self answer ;-)
